# Android UnsatisfiedLinkError when load /lib/arm/libpolarssl.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I implement the native library in my Android application. And get some crashes like below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
/data/user/0/com.gbox.android/_root/data/internal_app/com.company.android-
gep493u9x7yrZ9yoy5Lqtw==/lib/arm/libpolarssl.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

When I analyze the Bundle file (`.aab`), there is **no** `/lib/arm` directory inside it.

And when I refer to Android documentation the supported ABIS only: `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_64`. Also the native library supports those ABIS.

I wonder why the App is trying to lookup the native library in `/lib/arm`, and in what a condition that might possible?

Thank you